# How can I list the cname location of a printer in Active Directory?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, cname-record, network-printer

I'm working on a new print server running Windows Server 2008 R2. The shared printers will be listed in Active Directory. The print server has a host record with one name, but I want to users to connect using a different name, setup via a cname record on the dns server.

The problem is that these shared printers are listed in Active Directory using the host A record. I can choose to add the printer via the `\\cname\printername` share, but if I find the printer in Active Directory it will connect to the printer on the user's computer via `\\hostname\printername` instead, and this difference is highly visible to end users.  I would like the printers to be listed using the cname record, such that when users connect to a printer all they see is the cname.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was looking for a solution to this same problem and found that the "**uNCName**" property of the printqueue object in AD simply needs to be changed from **\\servername.domain.com\printerName** to **\\alias.domain.com\printerName**. Scripts to accomplish this are available here: [http://jthiede.wordpress.com/2012/08/20/list-a-printer-in-active-directory-using-a-cname](http://jthiede.wordpress.com/2012/08/20/list-a-printer-in-active-directory-using-a-cname/)/. The scripts use Quest Active Roles (http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx) so that will need to be installed wherever you run the scripts. Here is the basic syntax:

> set-QADobject SERVER-printer -objectattributes
>   @{servername=”alias.domain.com”;shortservername=”alias”;uNCName=”\\alias.domain.com\printer”}

Hope this helps!

-Jason

Comment: Awesome. Still need to do this manually whenever I add a printer, but it's not that big of a deal. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you found it helpful. You can actually set a scheduled task triggered by an event 306 in the PrintService event logs (if you enable those logs) to run the script for you. I setup a new queue today and it triggered the script when I listed it in the directory.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register the SPN's into active directory.

```
setspn.exe –a host/CNAME computerobject
```

Reference: http://daddyr.blogspot.com/2010/12/cname-on-windows-2008-r2-server-print.html

Comment: Warning that this will affect all services published by the server in Active Directory, not just Printers.

Comment: Edited the answer to reflect the additional step necessary for AD advertisement.

Comment: Doesn't work... I can already manually add a \\cname\printername share, which is what that post covers. The problem is that if I find the printer in active directory it connects via \\hostname\printername instead, and I want to active directory to use the cname when users connect to the printer.

Answer (score 1):

Use ADSI Edit.

```
Browse to the server object.
CN=Servername,CN=Computers,DC=Domain
```

Locate the printer you want to change and open the properties.

```
CN=Servername Printername
```

In attribute editor, scroll down to "serverName", modify the value to what ever you want.